# My ListView is not properly showing results

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

My second edition of my ListView troubles :( Here is my code:

```
   public class Person
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string NAME { get; set; }
        public string CODE { get; set; }
        public string CITY { get; set; }

    }     
    public List<Person> CL = new List<Person>() {
     new Person() { ID = "kkkkkkk", NAME = "dsdsdsd", CODE = "sdsdsd", CITY = "sdsdsdsd" },
     new Person() { ID = "kkkkkkk", NAME = "dsdsdsd", CODE = "sdsdsd", CITY = "sdsdsdsd" },
     new Person() { ID = "kkkkkkk", NAME = "dsdsdsd", CODE = "sdsdsd", CITY = "sdsdsdsd" },
     new Person() { ID = "kkkkkkk", NAME = "dsdsdsd", CODE = "sdsdsd", CITY = "sdsdsdsd" },
            };
```

Here is my xaml:

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CL }" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label  Text="{Binding ID}"></Label>
                        <Label Text="{Binding NAME}"></Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

It shows nothing on my page.
But when I use this everything works fine:

```
 public ObservableCollection<string> trials1 { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string> { "One","More","Character" };
```

And my xaml here:

```
<ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding trials1 }" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label  Text="{Binding .}"></Label>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Length}"></Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can only bind to public properties

this is NOT a property - it has no get/set

```
public List<Person> CL = new List<Person>() {
```

this IS a property

```
public List<Person> CL { get; set; } = new List<Person>() {
```